# Getting anchor element within SVG

Tags: jquery, svg

I have an svg on my site for selecting states in the US. The format is:

```
<svg...>
  <a xlink:href="...">
    <polygon ...><title>{stateName}</title></polygon>
  </a>
</svg>
```

After several hours of headaches trying to figure out why clicking the links caused issues with other scripts on the same site, I narrowed down the issue to the event not being passed to those functions when the target was the anchor in the svg.

So I created a separate page without those other scripts and experimented by creating the following function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('svg a').click(function(event){
          if(event.target.tagName == 'polygon'){
              var target = $(this).parent();
              alert('target: ' + dump(target));
          }else{
              alert('event: ' + dump(event.target));
          }
      });
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Note: The dump() function is a custom function that outputs the contents of objects and arrays.

My first version of this code just output the event.target.tagName which was always "polygon" even though the object I'm binding the click to is the anchor. So I modified it to get the polygon's parent but that returns the svg. It's like the anchor doesn't exist.

Why is it that I cannot seem that the event for that function doesn't contain any reference to the anchor? How can I get this to behave like it would if the anchor was inside a div instead?

I tried a jQuery SVG plugin but that did nothing.

TL;DR / Clarification
The issue isn't that the anchor isn't working, clicking it will take you to the page defined in xlink:href. But any jQuery code bound to click events that are triggered when clicking these anchors within the svg either come through with the event as undefined or not containing the expected anchor object data.

How can I get the appropriate event object for these anchors?

Edit: Finally got jsfiddle to load: http://jsfiddle.net/fja4Lt0L/

Explanation of current behavior in different browsers:

- FireFox: issue as described
- Chrome/Safari: does nothing at all
- IE: follows the link regardless of the script attached to the click event

None of those are behaviors expected of the script or intended by the coder.

Comment: Mind making a JSFiddle for this? What's the expected return of your click?

Comment: I will as soon as the site stops timing out for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SVG only graphics elements (lines, rectangles etc and text) can be the target of events. If you specify it on a container e.g. a `<g>` or `<a>` element then all their children become targets.

Just call `.parentElement` (if you're using raw DOM) or `.parent()` (if you're using jQuery) repeatedly on whatever the target is till you get an anchor element.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/oxgxzahk/) or with [jquery and .parent](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/oxgxzahk/1/)

Comment: The first time I use .parent() I get the <svg>. The second .parent() gets the <body> so I'm pretty sure that's not going to do it in this situation.

Comment: Your markup shows that the parent of the polygon is the anchor tag. Presumably your traversal code is buggy. You could alsays add it to the question so we can see.

Comment: Yes, you would expect that the anchor would be the object returned by .parent() but it isn't, it's the <svg>. That's exactly the problem I'm having. That's what I'm trying to figure out, "why does that .parent() return the <svg> and not the <a>?" As for the transversal code, there isn't any other than what you see up there. That script always triggers the if(event.target.tagName == 'polygon') condition and always alerts with the <svg> object instead of the expected <a> object.

Comment: Sure works for me, check the example I've added to my answer.

Comment: Cool, so then any idea why .parent() wouldn't work? And do you know any way to structure the code so that by default the value of event is the anchor object I need? I ask because my original problem is that this code interferes with other scripts I don't want to modify myself (they are supplied by contributors who currently aren't aware of this specific case)? To be clear, their scripts all attach to either general click events and perform actions based on the type of object or specifically bind to <a> clicks and use the event object for their actions.

Comment: I've expanded my answer to show that parent works and I've already answered the second question.